# Contextual Caching with Redis

Tags: caching, redis

I'd like to find a caching library/client for Redis that can take a set of key-value pairs and a value to be cached and associated with those pairs, and for lookups and faults to be performed **for** any of those pairs (a get operation for any of the key-value pairs given for a set operation to return that cached value, and a fault operation of any of those key-value pairs to fault the value and all of those associations). Supporting TTLs would be a bonus.

Does such a solution exist in the public-domain?